# Order of photo albums displayed by ALAssets library

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, alassetslibrary, alasset

I am using the `ALAssets` library to build a custom image picker controller (much like in the photos app). Specifically I'm using `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` to populate a list of albums so I can put them in a table. I'm noticing when using this method, it populates the list in reverse order as the photos app so the albums are displayed reversed. For example:

The photos app displays the albums this way: 
[image]

My app displays the albums this way: 
[image]

Obvious solution is for me to just add the albums to the front of my array instead of the back, however I wanted to know if this is the usual behavior or if this is a bug? "Test Row" and "Test Row 2" I created using the new option in ios5 that lets you create your own album in the photos app, but I wonder if you add albums through other ways (like through iPhoto which I'm unsure how to do), are they ordered correctly? Has anyone come across this?

Comment: Perhaps you are learning ALAssets library and your image picker does something pretty cool but you can achieve multi-image select with the regular imagePickerController. See if my post helps you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542487/select-multiple-images-from-photo-library

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible to change the order by which `AssetsLibrary` framework returns to the caller `ALAssetsGroup`s.