# Multiple-selection image picker

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I need an image picker that supports multiple selections for writing an app, something like Photos.

I have found out some solutions by searching, the problem is, choosing the best one. I thought it's much better to ask some experts.

List of solutions:

1. Using `ALAssetsLibrary`. The problem: as far as I read, it reads the user's geolocation and ask for permission, which I don't want.
2. [Using Apple API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542487/select-multiple-images-from-photo-library)
3. Using `ELCImagePickerController`. The problem: I've read that it crashes when there are more than about 100 photos.
4. Using `AGImagePickerController`. The problem: new release (Mar 12, 2012), lack of enough reviews and maybe unknown problems.

Do you agree about these problems? Is there any other solution? Which of the above is the best one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Assets Library will give you all Geo location Information

Comment: Hmm... tested here and ALAssetsLibrary ask the user location permission, for only the first time. Sadly.

Comment: Assets Library give you all the Geo location information hence app will get a prompt saying app is trying to access their location.

Answer (score 0):

This should work 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558307/1294448

The trick is to NOT `dismiss` the picker after `didFinishPickingImage` and `writeToFile` after each image is selected.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
.
.
.
// Get the data for the image
        NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
.
.
.
// and then we write it out
        [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile2 atomically:NO];
}
```

About the location :
Assets Library give you all the Geo location information hence app will get a prompt saying app is trying to access their location. No work around for this yet.