# iOS 7 Pick Photo From Photo Album, Edit Photo, Replace Original Photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to use UIImagePicker or Assets Library to select a photo, edit it, and then save that photo back as same (but edited) photo instead of saving it as a new photo (basically just overwrite the picked photo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...its a bad idea to override the original image, the rule of thumb is to always work with the copy of the original image. !

you can refer to  [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542487/select-multiple-images-from-photo-library)!  which explains how to select  image/s, store them and do anything with them after selection.