# select multiple images in imagepickercontroller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have tried lot of third party picker in ios for selecting multiple images/videos. Is there a way to select multiple images/videos using imagepickercontroller without using third party imagepicker..??

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280063/how-to-pick-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can do following

- Fetch all the images/video (whatever you want) from device.
- Create a view controller lets say `MyGalleryVC`.
- In `MyGalleryVC`, you need to display all the fetched images/videos in either collection view or table view.
- And finally you can set `allowsMultipleSelection` property of table view or collection view.
- Create a `delegate` method that will give you the selected images/videos.