# Use default UIImagePickerController to take multiple photos without preview before dismissing - Swift

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Been searching already, and there might be duplicates, but I don't have a clean solution for a newbie.

I want to use the default UIImagePickerController to take multiple photos only without showing the previews or dismissing the controller until I've taken a certain number of photos. Basically "clicking" away until you've taken, say, six photos. Then the Controller is dismissed.

Is there a way to do that without a custom class?

Comment: You need a third party library, I use this one https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using the default `UIImagePickerController` . You need to use a third party library to make this work.

Answer (score -1):

Check This Links this may be helpful to you

1. [How to select Multiple images from UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller)
2. [How to pick multiple images from UIImagePickerController in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280063/how-to-pick-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller-in-ios/21280134)

Comment: @mwevre Did you check it? Is it useful for you?