# How do i select multiple (2-5) images for an Image picker then return as image view?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Hey so I'm trying to have a button that when pressed allows the user to choose 2-5 pictures from their photo library then have whatever photo chosen be set onto a uiimageview? I was looking online and couldn't find anything related to how to do it in swift?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried searching https://www.cocoacontrols.com/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select Multiple Images from Photo Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542487/select-multiple-images-from-photo-library)

Answer (score 1):

I worked out using this : https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController .

Getting selected image's thumbnail images:

```
let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
pickerController.sourceType = .Photo
pickerController.didCancelled = { () in
    println("didCancelled")
}

pickerController.didSelectedAssets = { [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in
    println("didSelectedAssets")
    println(assets)

    for(var i = 0; i<(assets.count); i++){
        print(assets[i].url)

        self.PickedArray .addObject(assets[i].thumbnailImage!)
}

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToPhotoLibraryView", sender: self)
```

Getting selected image's urls :

```
assets[i].url instead of assets[i].thumbnailImage
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Currently iOS does not provide an image picker out of the box that lets you pick **multiple** images from the photo library. UIImagePickerController only lets you select one image.

But there are several image picker implementations available that let you pick multiple images. You can find a whole bunch at cocoacontrols.com as @ytbryan already mentioned.

I am currently not aware of any multiple image picker implemented in Swift. If someone finds one, please edit and post the link.