# multiple imagePicker from camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 3 image views on my view controller. I have an option like choose from gallery or take a picture. Now, what I want is from the camera. I want to pick images by default, we can pick one, but I want three how can we achieve it.

Comment: Did you check for existing answers in the community ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20756899/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-uiimagepickercontroller

Comment: UIImagePickerController doesn't allow you to select multiple images. You could try a custom ImagePickerController such as this one: https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController  but it might not work as expected as the class this library is built on (ALAssetsLibrary) has been deprecated as of iOS 9.

Comment: `we can pick one, but I want three how can we achieve it` can you explain these line in brief

Answer (score 3):

use `Tag` Concept`

**Step-1**

Initially assign the tag for your each imageView as `1,2,3` and crete the one common method for open the `UIImagePickerController`

**Step-2**

create the gesture for each image

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.delegate = self;
 imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

call method like

```
- (IBAction)handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender

{

UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Attach image" message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction* pickFromGallery = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take a photo"
                                                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                            if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
                                                            {
                                                                UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                                                                picker.view.tag = sender.view.tag;
                                                                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                                                                picker.delegate = self;
                                                                picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                                                                [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
                                                            }

                                                        }];
UIAlertAction* takeAPicture = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose from gallery"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                         UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                                                         picker.view.tag = sender.view.tag;
                                                         picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                                                         picker.delegate = self;
                                                         picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                                                         [self  presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
                                                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                               }];

[alertController addAction:pickFromGallery];
[alertController addAction:takeAPicture];
[alertController addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

**Step-3**

on that delegate method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
if(picker.view.tag == 1)
{
 // assign the image to first
}
else if(picker.view.tag == 2)
{
 // assign the image to second
}
else
{

// assign the image to third
}

}
```

Comment: @user3182143 - why we prepare third party , we can customize everything in our own code, and thanx a lot

Comment: It is useful for everyone.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I think original post is asking for picking three image with one attemp!!

Comment: @Lion - no bro is not possible , but we can apply the three images in single clik

Comment: yeah but op is asking for that!!!! And it is possible  by customization!!

Comment: Yes OP is asking for 3 images to be selected at a go and they be applied to 3 imageviews respectively.

Comment: If there is need like tap and pick image one by one then this answer is perfact with nice explanation!!

Comment: @Lion - tanx bro, lets we ask the qustioner clearly once

Comment: Btw questioner should use this approach because this is simpler. If there is three image view then he can pick three image one by one. There is no need to pick three image at once!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own logic something like,

In `didFinishPickingImage` increment one counter and don't dismiss `image picker` control until counter reaches at 3 and store image every time n local storage like in document directory or temp directory.

Refer accepted answer of [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542487/select-multiple-images-from-photo-library) for demonstration of what i have explained.

If you want to use third party library then [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)
 is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended two Third-party to you to pick multiple images and deal with to as you can :-

[1-ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

[2-CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController)

Comment: Both of them dont support device camera images.